# Why can I define a function in another function?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

see the code below, I define a function in another function,

```
void test1(void)
{
 void test2(void)
 {
   printf("test2\n");
 }
 printf("test1\n");
}

int main(void)
{
 test1();
 return 0;
}
```

this usage is odd,is it a usage of c89/c99 or only a extension of gcc (I used gcc 4.6.3 in ubuntu 12 compiled). I run this code and it output "test2" and "test1".test2 can be only called in test1.

What's more,what's the common scene  of this usage or what does this usage used for?

Comment: Its limiting the scope of `test2()` you cannot call it outside `test1()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

It's not C, it's not portable, and thus not very recommended unless you know that GCC will

- Be the only compiler used to build your code
- Will keep supporting this feature in future versions
- Don't care about [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: Of course if you have C++11, you can pretty much define nested functions with lambdas.

Comment: Is it possible to call only test1 and exclude execution of test2 ?

Comment: @bjskishore123, `auto test2 = []{printf("test2\n");};` will not execute it, but still act like a function definition for what it's worth.

Comment: @unwind if it is a gcc extension,what's the purpose of this usage?

Comment: @bjskishore123  i tried,if i don't call test2 in test1 and just define it,test2 will not run and i objdump the object file,i found that if don't call test2,test2's code will be ommited.

Comment: @chris, AFAIK you can execute lambdas immediately: `auto test3 = []{ return printf("test3\n"); }();` calls the lambda right after defining it.

Comment: @Ezio The purpose of allowing it is, I guess, that local functions is a useful thing to have. Often you have to instead declare `static` functions at the file level for functions that are only being used from with-in another (public or otherwise) function.

Comment: @chris: Don't need C++ lambda's. In C++98 you can define static methods inside local classes.

Comment: @CTMacUser: Doesn't even need a variable: `[]{ return printf("test3\n"); }();`. But that's getting suspiciously close to Perl.

Comment: @MSalters, Interesting, thanks. I suppose that might come in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

As written, it's not legal C++.  You can, however, define
a class within a function, and define functions in that class.
But even then, in pre C++11, it's still only lexical nesting;
the class you define does not "capture" any of the context of
the outer function (unless you implement the capture
explicitly); in a true nested function, the nested function can
access local variables in the outer function.  In C++11, you
*can* define a lambda function, with automatic capture.

The reason C and C++ never adopted nested functions is *because*
in order to make capture work, you need additional information,
with the result that a pointer to function becomes more complex.
With the result that either you cannot take the address of the
nested function (lack of orthogonality), a pointer to a nested
function is incompatible with a normal pointer to a function
(which ends up requiring too many external details to perculate
out), or all pointers to functions have the extra information
(and you pay for something you don't use most of the time).

Comment: The "capture", did you mean "closure"?

Comment: @Marcus - "capture" is the intent, "closure" is one implementation. Only the compiler is supposed to care about the closure, and it may choose a different implementation (though closures are normal for good reason).

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning - nested functions (with the context capturing) were first introduced in functional languages (taking them from lambda calculus), and all (or at least most) functional languages have them. In the imperative paradigm, the Pascal family has always had nested procedures, and some of the more recent C family have them - I'm pretty sure C#, Java, JavaScript, D, ActionScript and probably more.

Comment: @Marcus To extend on Steve314's response, I used "capture" because that is the word used in the C++ standard.  And as defined in C++, it is somewhat different than closure, as I know it.  In particular, in C++, capture can be implemented by copy _or_ by reference, it only affects specific variables, and it in no way affects the lifetime of those variables.

Comment: @Steve314, C# doesn't have them, but I use lambdas for this purpose -- basically something to replace the language's missing `#define` macros for testing over a static list of items (ie no runtime iteration).

Comment: @Blindy - good catch and, on checking, Java doesn't seem to have them either. Whoops!

Comment: @Steve314 How could C# or Java have nested functions?  In both languages, all functions must be a member of a class.

Comment: @James - yes, obviously today is my being-really-stupid day. In another question, I even managed to forget that factorial is an integer function. I should probably shut down this browser quick before I start recommending bubblesort.

Answer (score 2):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/gcc_5.html#SEC71

Nested functions explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions are only allowed in C but are seldomly used because they are visible within that function scope only. However if you want to workaround nested functions you can do something like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef void (*fptr)(void);
fptr test1(void) {
    void test2(void) {
        printf("test2\n");
    }
printf("test1\n");
return test2;
}
int main(void) {
    void (*f)(void);
    f = test1();
    f();
    return 0;
 }
```