# Is there a difference between "in-place" and "space complexity O(1)" or do they mean the same?

Tags: space-complexity, in-place

Do in place and space complexity O(1) mean different things? If yes, can someone explain the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585507/sorting-in-place may explain the difference

Answer (score 6):

Space complexity of O(1) is a stronger requirement than in-place, because O(1) implies that the changes are done in place, but not the other way around.

You can make an in-place algorithm that has a space complexity above O(1). For example, the recursive re-heapifying algorithm of [*Heapsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is in-place, but its recursive implementation without tail call optimization has an O(log N) space complexity.

Comment: Quick sort with recursive implementation is a good example of in place algorithm that has a space complexity higher than O(1).
It uses logN recursive calls at worst case, hence needs logN auxiliary space for the call stack.
But since it does the changes in place on the input array, it is considered in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think, Sergey's explanation is a bit confusing.

The terminology "in-place" is used for algorithms which **doesn't require additional Data Structures** to transform the input. However, to be considered as in-place algorithm, it **must have maximum of O(log(N)) space complexity** for additional pointers, pivots, stacks pointers. Any algorithm which requires more than O(log(N)) is not considered in-place algorithm

So, O(1) doesn't always mean it is in-place algorithm. For example, think of a method that returns random element from an array. You generate a random number with the index boundary of the input array, which requires O(1) space. And just return the matching value under the random index. But you are not transforming the input array. So, this is not in-place algorithm.

Comment: sorry but your explanation is even more confusing.
You give an example by comparing apples and oranges. in place is an attribute of algorithms transforming an input array.
No need to compare it with an algorithm that does not so.
Plus there is no maximum limit on the auxiliary space that a "in place" algorithm can use in my knowledge. can you please put a reference to that affirmation ?
I see on wikipedia that O(N) is accepted
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm

Comment: The 3rd paragraph of my answer is more counter argument to Sergey's "because O(1) implies that the changes are done in place, but not the other way around". I just gave him example where the algo uses O(1) space, but it is not in-place algo.

Comment: @Özgün, Regarding the O(log(N)) is max - this is from logical perspective. Why do you need in-place algo if you are using the same space as input - O(N)? Even your wiki states "anything in o(n) is allowed" which means (I think you have a bit problem with translation) -  that the space complexity can grow sub-linearly, but it cannot grow linearly or super-linearly with the size of the input n. So basically "in o(n)" means - less than o(n). You are welcome.

Comment: Not sure if it is a translation issue.
To me what "in o(N)" means is  ∀ f(x) ∈ o(N)

Comment: So you agree that you were a bit confusing when you stated "on wikipedia that O(N) is accepted" =)

Comment: no I do not. "anything in o(n) is allowed"  means o(N) is allowed.