# Custom 2D list sort with lambda expression (in 1 line) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, lambda

I have a python 2D list like this-

```
[[3,4],[1,2],[2,1],[6,5]]
```

I like to have it sorted in both direction, row and column-wise. So, my desired output would be like this-

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

What I have done is-

```
list.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

And what I am getting is-

```
[[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 5]]
```

Can anyone please help to sort it [`in-place`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585637/2193439) with [`lambda`](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#:%7E:text=Python%20does%20not%20encourage%20using,return%20one%20or%20more%20functions.) expression?

Comment: you cannot sort both your list as well the elements with single lamda expression used in key. You can use listcomprehension to sort each element and then use sort() on the new list to sort the whole list. Of course it could be in one line

Comment: Why would the sort “get the key” function *change* an entry? It won’t - and shouldn’t as things may break if this is actually done with the sort functions. You might want to *sort each pair as it’s own collection* (see list comprehension) in a the containing collection, and then *sort the collection of (internally sorted) pairs*.

Comment: What is the purpose of `key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` parameter (and `lambda`) is not meant to modify the content of the `list`. Instead, it is meant to be used for sorting according to how each element evaluates when the `key` function is applied.
However, you can use `key`'s side-effects to achieve what you are after by calling `.sort()` on your `key`'s function's argument. Since `.sort()` result is just `None`, you also need to provide the statement itself to be used for the actual sorting:

```
l = [[3,4],[1,2],[2,1],[6,5]]

l.sort(key=lambda x: (x.sort(), x))

print(l)
# [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

This is not considered good programming practice, though.

A cleaner and much more efficient, but obviously not 1-line, the approach would be:

```
l = [[3,4],[1,2],[2,1],[6,5]]
for x in l:
    x.sort()
l.sort()

print(l)
# [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

---

The `key` based approach is also significantly less efficient since it tries to sort the inner lists at each `key` call which we should expect to occur `n log n` times, against the `n` times strictly required, thus some of the inner lists is inevitably being sorted more than necessary. Instead, looping through the outer list explicitly sort each internal list once.

Just to give some ideas of the timings:

```
import random
import copy
import collections


def double_sort_loop(seq):
    for x in seq:
        x.sort()
    seq.sort()


def double_sort_deque(seq):
    collections.deque(map(lambda x: x.sort(), seq), maxlen=0)
    seq.sort()


def double_sort_key(seq):
    seq.sort(key=lambda x: (x.sort(), x))


def gen_input(n, m, v_min=None, v_max=None):
    if v_min is None:
        v_min = 0
    if v_max is None:
        v_max = v_min + (2 * m * n)
    return [[random.randint(v_min, v_max) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]


random.seed(0)

base = gen_input(100000, 10)

%timeit seq = copy.deepcopy(base); double_sort_loop(seq)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
%timeit seq = copy.deepcopy(base); double_sort_deque(seq)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
%timeit seq = copy.deepcopy(base); double_sort_key(seq)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do all this in-place and in one-line, you can achieve it with something horrendous like this:

```
vals = [[3, 4], [1, 2], [2, 1], [6, 5]]

vals.sort(key=lambda x: (lambda x, dummy: (x[1], x[0]))(x, x.sort()))

print(vals)
```

Output: `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

While this does fit your requirements, it is inefficient and impossible to read. I'd strongly suggest doing it properly as noted in other answers.

Comment: What is the point of having a double lambda expression? The actual job is being done by `x.sort()` anyway. To have the outer list sorting only after the inner list sorting, you just need to call it before `x`. Therefore, you can simplify the code quite a bit and use a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort inplace as you need to create a modified list of inner elements first. The best you can do is

```
[sorted(x) for x in my_list].sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], k[1]))
```

Comment: that's not what OP asks for. and is overcomplicated. same could be done with `sorted_list = sorted([sorted(item) for item in my_list])`

Comment: Hi, I like to have `in-pace` sorting with no extra space (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585637/2193439), is that possible?

Comment: @EhteshamSiddiqui, my code will produce `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` - exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @EhteshamSiddiqui, you are completely confused. with input `[[2, 1], [1, 1]]` the result will be `[[1, 1], [1, 2]]` - as expected.